# SQL Max by date and term

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have some data that look like this:

```
table
```

[image]

I would like to get, by term, the most recent upload date

I've tried this but I know I have placed the term parameters in the wrong place because I only got the max date of the whole group instead of max date within both the `1` term and the `4` term.

```
SELECT Inst, Term, Year, FreezeDate, UploadDate, RecordCount, ErrorCount, FileName, System, 
FROM table
WHERE UploadDate=(
SELECT MAX(UploadDate) FROM table WHERE System = ('a') and Year = ('2017') and Inst = ('123') and (Term = ('1') or Term = ('4')))
```

My ideal output would be this:
[image]

Could someone assist?

Comment: Instead of doing it in the where clause, do a join on a subquery with the columns you want to group by and the Max(uploaddate)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a subquery grouped by term and with max upload date, then join on your table

```html
SELECT t.*
FROM table t
   JOIN (SELECT Term, MAX(UploadDate) as MaxUploadDate FROM table GROUP BY Term) tmud 
      ON t.term = tmud.term AND t.UploadDate = tmud.MaxUploadDate
```

Comment: Thank you! pardon my ignorance but where would i put the other parameters like `WHERE System = ('a') and Year = ('2017') and Inst = ('123')`

Comment: Don't think it matters but it would be more efficient to add your WHERE clause to the subquery between FROM and GROUP BY.